# Spark streaming (run-example vs spark-submit)

Tags: python, spark-streaming, flume-ng

It's a follow up question to [Spark with Flume (configuration/classpath?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33590622/spark-with-flume-configuration-classpath)

Got that problem stored after trying a few things, the problem I now have is

$spark-submit --jars /opt/scala/spark-streaming-flume_2.10-1.5.1.jar --master local[*] /home/user/spark/FlumeStreaming.py

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.flume import FlumeUtils

sc = SparkContext(appName="Newapp")
strm = StreamingContext(sc,1)

flume = FlumeUtils.createStream(strm,"localhost",9999)

lines = flume.map(lambda x: x[1])
counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) \
        .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
        .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
counts.pprint()

strm.start()
strm.awaitTermination()
```

---

```
15/11/07 23:55:09 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flume/source/avro/AvroSourceProtocol
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.flume.FlumeReceiver.responder$lzycompute(FlumeInputDStream.scala:147)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.flume.FlumeReceiver.responder(FlumeInputDStream.scala:146)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.flume.FlumeReceiver.initServer(FlumeInputDStream.scala:163)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.flume.FlumeReceiver.onStart(FlumeInputDStream.scala:170)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.startReceiver(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:148)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.ReceiverSupervisor.start(ReceiverSupervisor.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:542)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverTrackerEndpoint$$anonfun$9.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:532)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$37.apply(SparkContext.scala:1984)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$37.apply(SparkContext.scala:1984)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flume.source.avro.AvroSourceProtocol
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 16 more

15/11/07 23:55:09 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
15/11/07 23:55:09 ERROR ReceiverTracker: Deregistered receiver for stream 0: Stopped by driver
```

The question I have is, it's the same code as the flume_wordcount.py provided in spark examples, the one in the example works fine, but my version doesn't work. The difference is the way it's run one with run-example and the other one with spark-submit, which points to the way classpath and jar files are managed. Is there something I should do?

Answer (score 0):

Sorted this out, had to have the right jar and pass it to spark-submit

```
$spark-submit --jars /path/to/spark-streaming-flume-assembly*.jar FlumeStreaming.py localhost 12345
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use spark-streaming-flume_2.10-1.5.1.jar which has its dependency. You can download the assembly jar in http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-flume-assembly_2.10 then run as what you did above.

Hope it helps.